# Building wheel for package failed: Permission denied when using pip in virtualenv wrapper

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv

Recently I try to learn the virtualenv wrapper, and I also read some posts on SO, but still don't know what's the best way to solve my problem...

The following is the steps I create an environment and using pip to install package.

```
mkvirtualenv -p python3 envtest
pip install markdown
```

However the stdout shows the following message:

```
Building wheel for markdown failed: [Errno13] Permission denied: '/Users/haha/Library/Caches/pip/wheels/ee'
```

while I can just use the following command to change the owner of the folder from root to haha:

```
sudo chown haha wheels
```

But I don't know is that the most correct way to handle this situation?
Since originally I thought virtualenv wrapper should not touch any global folder like something under Library folder?

p.s. I use MAC OS X

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is the output for `which pip`? I suspect it's pointing to a global install and not one in your virtual environment. You'll need to use the one in the virtual environment.

Comment: Actually not, this is under the local environment folder.

Comment: Have you activated your virtual environment?

Comment: Yes. There is my environment name before the command line prompt. I use workon env_name to start the environment

Answer (score 9):

I got stuck in a similar error, and I solved this with something like this:

`$ pip install markdown --no-cache-dir`

If you run `pip --help` you will find:

`--no-cache-dir              Disable the cache.`

Hope that it can help to someone in the future.

Comment: Helped me, thanks! Occured when I had the module (pyperclip) installed globally before switching into `venv`.